# R Adding a title to pdf output of frequencies

Tags: r

So this code runs without error and creates a pdf of the frequency, but won't give me any text above the frequency.
Also, that's probably more libraries than what you need.  I've been fiddling with a few things and I don't remember what's in where.

I've tried adding a title as:

```
grid.text
grid.draw
grid.table
```

and none of them work.

```
library(gtable, grid, gridExtra)
mpg <- freq(mtcars$mpg)


pdf("mtcars.pdf", height=11, width=8.5)
  title <- "Miles per gallon"

  grid.text(title)
  grid.table(mpg)
dev.off()
```

Does anyone know how to add a title in a pdf on top of frequency output?  Or at least some work around that might work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are printing the table over the title. So if you specify coordinates for the title, you can adjust it:

```
library(gtable, grid, gridExtra)
mpg <- Freq(mtcars$mpg)


pdf("mtcars.pdf", height=11, width=8.5)
title <- "Miles per gallon"

grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.text(title,x = (0.5), y = (0.6))
grid.table(mpg)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I ran it, but i'm still not getting a title.  I deleted the old pdf just in case and ran it again and still no title.  I copied your code exactly.  All i'm getting is the freq.  I have R 3.6, and RStudio 1.2.5019. I just downloaded it Monday.

Comment: Also, what's the grid::grid.text part?  I read the help and it doesn't explain anything to me.  Something about spaces in the package?

Comment: Ok, so i removed grid.table(mpg) and ran it just to see what would happen, and I got the title.  But when i put grid.table(mpg) back in, the title's gone again.  ???